# I am using GRID in CSS and trying to make a map layout. but the layout is not coming in full screen. how to do this in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, css-grid

below is the html code for the layout: which uses json input to create grids dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Booking</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div *ngFor="let parking of parkings;let i=index; let x=index;">
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the SCSS part of the code:

```
.grid-container {
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columnmax),60px);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(0px, auto);
  padding-top:  var(--scrHalfHeight);
  padding-left: var(--scrHalfWidth);
  justify-content: center;
}    

.grid-item {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #00ff73;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

this is the TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import parkingData from "./layout.json";
interface Parking {
  row: String;
  value: String;
  column: String;
  number: String;
  direction: String;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  parkings: Parking[] = parkingData;
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

the current output looks something like this: attached image
[image]

**question: how to remove the white background. or make the "grid-container" fit to screen?**

EDIT:
After removing padding and using
`body{width: 100vw;height: 100vh;}`
I get the output like this:
[image]

Comment: add to styles.scss `body { width: 100vw, height: 100vh }` and tell me what happens

Comment: nothing really happened

Comment: The whitespace is the padding you've added to the top left and right

Comment: i have removed padding i said. there is no padding

Comment: ok. I don't really know what to do now.. but is there any better way to make such layout as shown in the image? i tried flex box but had the same issue. any other way to create map(layout) dynamically?

Comment: check the sandbox for the working code demo - [link] https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-layout-demo-3tvuhg

Answer (score 2):

You have three statements in your CSS that are causing your problem.

The most important is `justify-content: center`.  [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) deliberately attempts to align the items in the grid at the center of the container.  If you want them to stretch to fill the container you need to remove this statement.

The other two statements that may be causing problems are `padding-top:  var(--scrHalfHeight)` and `padding-left: var(--scrHalfWidth)`.  These statements attempt to [put padding in](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding-top.asp) at the top and left of the grid respectively.  The amount of the padding is defined by --scrHalfHeight/--scrHalfWidth which are CSS variables which will be defined somewhere else in your code.  We can't see these variables in the code above, but their names seem to imply that they have been calculated at half screen height and width.  Again, just removing these lines should remove the padding.

You will probably also need the code in the other answers here to force the grid container itself to fill the width and height of the screen (`width: 100vw; height: 100vh;` in the .grid-container definition).

Below is a simplified version of your code that shows that if you add width and height and take out the three lines then this forces our grid items, which have a green background, to fill the screen.  If you put the three lines commented out back in (which isn't actually very easy to do in a snippet!) then you would see that they are centred, do not fill the screen, and are offset from the top and left:

```css
/* Don't add to the actual project - some values for the CSS variables we can't see  */
:root {
  --scrHalfHeight:25px;
  --scrHalfWidth: 25px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columnmax), 60px);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(0px, auto);
  /* Set the grid to fill the width and height of the screen */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  /* Take out 3 lines below for grid items to fill screen */
  /* padding-top: var(--scrHalfHeight);
  padding-left: var(--scrHalfWidth);
  justify-content: center; */
}

.grid-item {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #00ff73;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Booking</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item">1</div>
      <div class="grid-item">2</div>
      <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: kindly check the edited question- i have uploaded the output. there are white gaps between each row. how to solve this

Comment: I think that the gaps in the content must be coming from however the grid is being populated, because there's nothing in the code you've shown us that would do that.

Comment: kindly check the html file. i have edited it. also added TS file. in css the line - ` grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columnmax), 60px); ` where var(--columnmax) sets limit to number of columns... in TS file a json file is read and stored and exported the variable which is used with ngFor loop to create the grid dynamically

Comment: check the sandbox for working code -[link] https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-layout-demo-3tvuhg